# How exactly works this properties file that "include" some other properties file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, properties-file

I have the following doubt related a Java properties file.

Into a project I have a **config.properties** file that contains something like these lines:

```
Mailer=C:/Projects/MY-PROJECT/src/config/mailer.properties
Upload=C:/Projects/MY-PROJECT/src/config/upload.xml
Soap=C:/Projects/MY-PROJECT/src/config/soap.xml
Libretto=C:/Projects/MY-PROJECT/src/config/libretto.properties
```

So what is the exact meaning of these lines into a properties file? I think that is how I am including the content of 2 .properties file (**mailer.properties** and **libretto.properties**) and of 2 .xml file (**upload.xml** and **soap.xml**)

Is it right or is it a wrong interpretation?

Tnx

Comment: wrong!! you can use these property values any where in your app. basically property file are best for maintainable so you can change property's value anytime. it will not include content of whatever value it is defined!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties is a very simple format and does not support any kind of import. Such logic (if required) must be implemented at application level.

This means that exact meaning of properties file snippet that you posted can be discovered by examining code of your application. I suppose that this file contains references to other files, so somewhere in your application exists code that parses this file, extracts paths to other files and reads them too.